# Edge browser menu item hover glitch

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

Been battling with this for a few days - finally caving in and asking for help.

I'm experiencing a super weird issue in the Edge browser.

Here's the test site: http://edge22.com/test-edge/

When you hover over the menu items, a 1px line appears below the menu item you hovered. There's no border, text-decoration etc.. If the white header area is made black, the line is black etc..

It's like the height of the menu item is reducing by 1px only on hover: http://screencast.com/t/Lpkow3HF0

Now the weird part. This only happens when the element right before the navigation is a link (the "Test" link). If this link is removed, the glitch disappears.

Now if I wrap the link in a div and give it a small margin, the issue goes away:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:0.1em;"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? I've stripped all of the CSS down to nothing, and can't pinpoint the problem.

Comment: This looks like a rounding bug while trying to scale to handle zoom. Something somewhere is getting rounded up, while another element is getting rounded down. I would look for a mix of em and px, or elements that get their height based off of text while others are hard coded.

Comment: This is a rendering bug. Don't bother fixing it.

Comment: Unfortunately your link is dead. If you’re still having the problem can you update it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it could fix your problem (as it's not available anymore), but it fixed mine...  So for others looking for Edge artefacts that occur on hover ...

I had a somewhat similar issue where a line would appear totally without reason on some elements (and not on other elements using the same style on the same page). 
In my case it damaged a menu bar under a fractionally sized image with great repeatability upon hover (and even when not hovering anymore the damage remained). 
Simplest solution I found: add a border to the parent in the same color as the background that was damaged ; problem solved.